# PnP Monitor not detected after reboot

Tags: windows-7, multiple-monitors, display, dvi

My second monitor *only* works when I first disconnect and then reconnect the DVI cable *while Windows is running*. If I reboot or sleep and wake up, it stays dark. The other Monitor works fine.

I have Windows 7 64 Bit with an ATI HD 4770. Any ideas?

Comment: Laptop or desktop?

Comment: Sorry, Desktop. Thought the video card would give it away.